# shm_open() returning Invalid argument in mac

Tags: c, macos, system-calls

I am creating a shared object using the following call:

```
fd = shm_open("AMP_SHTDWN_HDLR_48EEA9463DAAFF59", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0777);
```

but it returns -1 and errno sets to 22 [EINVAL].
I have tried creating directory `shm` under `/dev` and inserting `'/'` in front of name as I read from other references that slash-less name is undefined, but that too didn't help. Is there something specific to OS X as compare to linux in this scenario.

Comment: Have you tried specifying a path to which you have write access (i.e. one where you could create a file)?

Comment: @KenThomases I have given write permissions to /dev/shm .Also, I should get [EACCESS] or alike in case there was problem with permissions.

Comment: What does /dev/shm have to do with anything?

Comment: @KenThomases you can check Notes here: http://linux.die.net/man/3/shm_open

Comment: @cbinder I think you should look in Apple's docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/shm_open.2.html

Comment: shm_open just crete a new file descriptor and you don't need to do anything directly on your filesystem. Try also to run shm_unlink() before shm_open. Which version of OS X are you running? Are you using the default clang compiler?

Comment: @cbinder, and what do the Linux man pages have to do with anything on OS X? There's no such thing as /dev/shm on OS X and no significance if you manually create such a thing.

Comment: @terencehill Using gcc on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Comment: And did you tried to unlink first? It sounds strange to me seems  that is not supported on your system. I used shared memory calls on OS X 10.6.8, 10.9 and subsequents so on both gcc and clang. I followed this guide and the relative man pages http://man7.org/training/download/posix_shm_slides.pdf

Comment: Can you post a little bit more code?